# How do email apps keep alive in the background?

Tags: android

I want to know how to ensure your app stays alive, *without* the persistent notification method.

The most common solution I see is to have a sticky notification permanently on, which will keep the app alive.

But how do email apps do it? Outlook and Gmail and K9 don't have a notification permanently at the top of the screen, so there must be another way?

So far I have tried START_STICKY, and I've tried disabling battery optimisation on the app, but overnight it will still get killed for some reason, yet I can see apps like Outlook have been running for several days without me even having to open them.

Answer (score 2):

> How do email apps keep alive in the background?

They don't.

> I want to know how to ensure your app stays alive, without the persistent notification method.

Create your own custom firmware build of Android and install that on your own hardware.

> Outlook and Gmail and K9 don't have a notification permanently at the top of the screen, so there must be another way?

Yes: they let their processes terminate.

Outlook and Gmail could use Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) to restart their processes if/when needed for incoming messages. K9 uses `WorkManager` to poll mail servers periodically. Neither require continuously-running processes.

Also bear in mind that apps that are pre-installed, are from Google, or are from the device manufacturer do not have to play by the same rules that apps from developers like you and me have to.